# Chrome changed behavior for drag and drop links

Tags: google-chrome

Chrome used to open links that were dropped into the window or tab in the same tab I dropped them in. This has recently changed to where chrome opens a new tab if you drop a link.

Is there a way to restore the previous behavior ?

Answer (score 1):

I would like to have the old behavior back too.
Opening a new tab 100% messes with my workflow since I have to check several links one by one and don't want 30 tabs created.